# Programmatic return type or casting for getting, and calling methods of, a child with a generic parent

Tags: java, generics, casting, abstract-class

### -Project Classes-

Class A:

```java
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D d = new D();
        B.set(d);

        d.add(new H()); //$ (correct error)
        B.get().add(new H()); //! (no error)
    }
}
```

Class B:

```java
public class B {
    protected static C c;

    public static C get() {
        return B.c;
    }

    public static void set(C c)
        B.c = c;
}
```

Class C:

```java
public abstract class C<T> {
    protected ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void add(T element) {
        this.array.add(element);
    }
}
```

Class D:

```java
public class D extends C<G> {
    //
}
```

Class E:

```java
public class E extends C<H> {
    //
}
```

Class F:

```java
public abstract class F<T> {
    //
}
```

Class G:

```java
public class G extends F<X> {
    //
}
```

Class H:

```java
public class H extends F<Y> {
    //
}
```

### -Class Roles-

1. `A` is the main class
2. `B` is a class that stores an object reference
3. `C` is a generic class that defines an array of objects
4. `D` & `E` extend `C` with different types
5. `G` & `H` extend `F` with different types

### -Logic Issue-

In `A.main()`, `//!` represents where the issue lies and `//$` represents the desired behavior. Because `B.get()` returns abstract type `C`, adding an illegal element to `array` is able to be done (in this example, adding `H` when only `G` is legal due to `D`'s extension of `C`).

The type of the returned object from `B.get()` is not known in the program (because `B.c` can represent an object of either type `D` or type `E`), so a modification to `B` to check `c`'s type and return it or automatically cast it in the call of `B.get()` is ideal, if possible.

### -Question Edits-

For clarification, casting with `((D) B.get()).add(new H());` is unhelpful as the child type that B.c holds is unknown. If it is possible to do something similar to `((B.get().getClass()) B.get()).add(new H())`, that would be helpful. The solution I would opt for would preferably be a change of or in the method `B.get()` rather than in the main method, if possible.

For further clarification, the outcome of solving this issue **is supposed to result in an error** as to prevent undesired adding of illegal types to arrays when referenced from `B.get()` (`//!` represents where no error occurs and `//$` represents where the error occurs *as it should*). I am open to re-writing how to save references to instances of `D` and `E` in `B` if a dynamic way of referring to the type of `C` can be done (type `D` or type `E`) can be done.

Comment: Your program was always going to have dangerous potential type bugs the moment you put `C` as the type of the static field in `B` without a type argument.

Comment: `D` is supposed to work with `G`s, not `H`s.

Comment: Basically an elaborate duplicate of "What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?"

Answer (score 0):

Generic types only work at compile time. It sounds like you're trying to make generics do dynamic type-safety, which is something they are terrible at doing because of erasure. Using `B` as a singleton whose static `c` has ever-changing type is incredibly awkward. You could attempt to retain a mapping from `Class<?>` to `C<?>` in B and fetch the appropriate one before trying to call `add`, I guess.

Also, at `//$` you simply used the wrong subclass.

```
d.add(new G());
```

type-checks correctly.

Here's what I meant:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D d = new D();
        B.put( G.class, d);
        B.get( H.class ).add(new H()); // dynamic typing, but susceptible to null as written
        d.add(new G()); //$ (no longer causes error)
    }
}

public class B {
    protected static Map< Class<?>, C<?> > mapC;

    public static <T> C<T> get( Class<T> clsT ) {
        return ( C< T > )mapC.get( clsT );
    }

    public static < T > void put(Class< T > clsT, C<T> c) {
        mapC.put( clsT, c );
    }
}

public abstract class C<Type> {
    protected ArrayList<Type> array = new ArrayList<Type>();

    public void add(Type element) {
        this.array.add(element);
    }
}

public class D extends C<G> {
    //
}

public class E extends C<H> {
    //
}

public abstract class F<Type> {
    //
}

public class G extends F<String> {
    //
}


public class H extends F<Integer> {
    //
}
```